# How to shallow render everything except sub react components or specify a depth

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, reactjs, jestjs

I have a component:

```
class PlayerProfile extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { name, avatar } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className="player-profile">
        <div className="inline-block">
          <Avatar src={avatar}/>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

And I want to test this using "shallow rendering":

```
describe('PlayerProfile component - testing with shallow rendering', () => {
  beforeEach(function() {
   let {TestUtils} = React.addons;

    this.TestUtils = TestUtils;

    this.renderer = TestUtils.createRenderer();
    this.renderer.render(<PlayerProfile name='user'
                                            avatar='avatar'/>);
  });

  it('renders an Avatar', function() {
    let result = this.renderer.getRenderOutput();

    expect(result.type).toEqual('div');
    expect(result.props.className).toEqual('player-profile');

    // Now the children
    expect(result.props.children).toEqual(
      <div className="inline-block">
        <Avatar src='avatar'/>
      </div>
    );
  });
});
```

I expect "shallow rendering" to render everything except other React components. But since it's 1 level deep, this test fails.

What it should be instead is:

```
 expect(result.props.children).toEqual(
      <div className="inline-block">
      </div>
    );
```

So I can't reach to `Avatar` because it is deeply nested.

How can I specify a depth using "shallow rendering"?

Even better:

How can I render every React element except custom React components in this case `Avatar`?

Comment: I don't know how open you are to using a different test framework, but if you are willing to use Jasmine instead of Mocha/Jest, there is an excellent suite of helper functions called 'jasmine-react' that I use in my application that allows you to replace subcomponents with a test double, among many other things.  https://github.com/tommyh/jasmine-react.  If you want to make the switch, I can post an answer here that uses that instead.

Comment: I am using karma mocha but I can't mock components. please post your answer I just want it to work, also see what I use at my issue https://github.com/badsyntax/react-seed/issues/18 @MichealParker. Finally I have this other related question as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31475048/how-to-isolate-and-iterate-over-individual-react-components-in-a-react-applicati

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you asked for my answer in the comments, I'll try my best to address the questions you asked.

The first question you asked is how you could specify a depth with shallow-rendering.  I can't really answer your question, but I still think I can help that failing test to pass.  What you're really looking for is a way to make sure that an `<Avatar/>` component is rendered when rendering your `<PlayerProfile/>` component, as `<Avatar/>` is a child of `<PlayerProfile/>`.  I would not use shallow-rendering for this.  Instead, why not try something like this:

```
var React = require('react/addons');
var TestUtils = React.addons.TestUtils;
var PlayerProfile = require('./playerprofile.jsx'); //or whatever your jsx file is called

describe('PlayerProfile', function () {

    it('renders an Avatar', function () {
        var Avatar = require('./avatar.jsx'); //or whatever your jsx file is called
        var playerProfile = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<PlayerProfile name='user' avatar='avatar'/>);
        var numberOfAvatars = TestUtils.scryRenderedComponentsWithType(playerProfile, Avatar).length;
        expect(numberOfAvatars).toEqual(1);
    });

});
```

This will fully render the `<Avatar/>` component (assuming it is a child of `<PlayerProfile/>`), and test to make sure that it exists.  Now, if your `<Avatar/>` component has some unwanted behavior that occurs when it is rendered, you would instead want to stub out this component so that behavior does not occur, which brings me to your second question...

The library I mentioned in the comments, [jasmine-react](https://github.com/tommyh/jasmine-react), has the ability to stub out components so that when they are rendered, a stub is rendered instead.  These stubs have only the minimum behavior required for a valid React component by default.

Unfortunately, using the jasmine-react helper functions would require you to switch to using Jasmine instead of Mocha, but this is the best way I know how to accomplish what you're looking for.  The [example](https://github.com/tommyh/jasmine-react#replacing-a-components-subcomponent-with-a-test-double) they provide does a good job illustrating its functionality.

I hope this helps!  Let me know if I failed to address some of the concerns you had.