# How to isolate and iterate over individual React components in a React application

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mocha.js, jestjs

React hot loading is very nice.

There are some React components that are mounted after some user interaction. I want to implement these components separated from the application.

I don't want to separate them as different npm modules though. I just want to mount them to the landing page and implement.

This is like having a test runner that runs each component separately not for testing, but for implementing it live (changing css etc.).

Is this possible somehow?

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand what you are trying to ask here.  Do you want to separate each of your components into their own .jsx file?  Or are you looking for something else?

Comment: I want to render a component into a page where I can visit in the browser and iterate on just that single component apart from the rest of the application. @MichaelParker

Comment: This can be done manually but I am looking for a tool that can automate this with helpful features.

Comment: Some type of https://github.com/gaearon/redux-devtools. Where It lists each component in my app, where I can select one so it renders on the page, and I can change it's code and see it's live.

Comment: I understand now.  Best there is (that I'm aware of) is react-devtools: https://github.com/facebook/react-devtools.  It has some helpful features, like telling you a component's current props or state, but it doesn't quite give you everything you're looking for.  I'm not sure that there is currently a tool out there that does.

Answer (score 0):

You're describing something like a decomposed "style guide" page I think. Check out this gulp task: https://github.com/pocotan001/react-styleguide-generator it sounds close.